# Quadratic Casimir of SO(5)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In the article *A Four Dimensional Generalization of the Quantum Hall Effect,* [arXiv:cond-mat/0110572](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0110572), by Zhang and Hu 
Quadratic Casimir operator for $SO(5)$ is given as

$$p^2/2+q^2/2+2p+q .$$

When $SO(5)$ irreducible representations are labelled by $(p,q)$

But In Iachello's book *Lie algebras and Applications,* it is given as

$$2p^2+6p+2q^2+2q.$$

Why are those two different?

Comment: There are two independent Casimir operators for $so(5)$, but to say something more I would need the link to Iachello's text.

Comment: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=188AE24B895D2F8CC835E5EFF2C4CB8D   here is a link for the book